# DD_INSERT in the update strategy transformation

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-management

Informatica automatically inserts all the rows to the target...so why do we have to use update strategy transformation (DD_INSERT) to insert the records???

Answer (score 1):

Good Question and you don't have to in case of insert only/update only case.

This assumption that *informatica automatically inserts all the rows to the target* is not true always. Yes, by default it inserts but there are many cases when we want to only update/only insert/delete/insert or update/reject the data.

Update strategy is used to control those scenarios.

`DD_INSERT` - This option is only to insert data.
`DD_UPDATE` - This updates the data based on key defined in target.
`DD_REJECT` - This rejects the data.
`DD_DELETE` - This deletes the data based on key defined in target.
Session should be data driven.

So, in your case, you can either mention dd_insert or set the session properties to `insert only`.
if you want to insert new data but update old data, you need to use dd_insert or dd_update.
if you want to insert new data but ignore old data, you need to use dd_insert or dd_reject.
if you want to only update old data, you need to use dd_update or set the session properties to `update only`..

Comment: Thanks for the information.
let us suppose my target already has the data 

id,name
1,vinay
2,kaushik

if I've used an update strategy transformation(only DD_INSERT) here and let us suppose if tomorrow i received the below file

id,name
1,kumar
3,kaushik

what happens to both the records here????? kindly let me know

Note: Id key is the primary key here

Comment: If session set to insert only and upd strategy set to dd_insert, infa will try to insert into the target. It will fail with primary key violated error. If database doesn't have any key defined, infa will simply insert all without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Update strategy transformation is used when you want handy logic to check insert/update/delete records by comparing source key columns with target key columns. for each type of update strategy transformation, you can choose how you want to process your data. below link examples by Informatica will help you to understand this:

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/constants/dd_insert/examples.html

You can achieve the same by using a lookup and setting IUD Flag in expression transformation and then based on each flag you can route different types of records (ins, upd, del) into different target to update target in different ways.

Informatica is giving you read to use logic in the form of Update strategy transformation and dd_insert is one type of that.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
let us suppose my target already has the data 

id,name
1,vinay
2,kaushik

if I've used an update strategy transformation(only DD_INSERT) here and let us suppose if tomorrow i received the below file

id,name
1,kumar
3,kaushik

what happens to both the records here????? kindly let me know

Note: Id key is the primary key here

Comment: Mapping will try to insert both the records but database will insert only 3,kaushik and it will reject 1, kumar because of the primary key on Id. So you should handle this by adding dd_update on Id which will update 1,kumar in the database.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that insert is the default behavior, it may be changed on session properties. See the [Treat Source Rows As property documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/sources/working-with-relational-sources/defining-the-treat-source-rows-as-property.html).

Only when you want to build a logic and decide what to do with a particular row, you should use `Data Driven` property value and then use DD_INSERT and other values according to your needs.